# Systemd - do not log output from particular service, but forward to syslog

Tags: syslog, systemd, journald

Is it possible for `systemd` to not log data from particular `service`, but to still forward it to the `syslog`?

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

Comment: Do you need to have rsyslog running too ?

Comment: I don't want to have logs in system journal, but still have it forwarded to syslog, syslog is running and receiving messages, but journald logs are filling with extra messages.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830129

Comment: @alex thanks, that doesn't help data is still stored in systemd journal